# How to style Material UI TextField component with Modular CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the border color of the Material UI TextField component using Modular CSS, but when I try to, it does not work.

CSS (In Styles.module.css):

```
.formInput {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-family: Roboto, serif !important;
    color: #057FA8 !important;
    border-color: #057FA8 !important;
}

.formInput:hover {
    border-color: #057FA8 !important;
}
```

JS:

```
import styles from './Styles.module.css';

...

<TextField id="name" name="name" label="Name" className={styles.formInput} value={formik.values.name} onChange={formik.handleChange}
                           error={Boolean(formik.errors.name)} helperText={formik.errors.name}
                           onBlur={(e) => {
                               e.preventDefault();
                               formik.validateField('name');
                               formik.setFieldTouched('name');
                           }}
                           margin='normal'
                           fullWidth
                           variant="outlined"
                />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason this has to be done with a CSS module? If you are using MUI why not just use their theming?

Comment: All of the code is using a CSS module. It would be really nice to continue that. Also, I need to be able to import the CSS module and to be able to use these styles without any more configuration. It would be really nice to not have to continuously copy code from file to file.

Comment: Are you using MUI 5 or 4?

Comment: I think I am using MUI 4

Comment: In package.json do you have the package `@mui/material` or `@material-ui/core`

Comment: I have both in my package.json

Comment: but I am using @material-ui/core

Answer (score 0):

Material UI V4 provides a [classes](https://v4.mui.com/api/text-field/#props) property on TextField that lets you style the internal components.

Based on this [example](https://v4.mui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs) you should be able to try:

```css
/* LABEL STYLES */
.formInput label.Mui-focused
{
    color: #057FA8 !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Roboto, serif
}

/* INPUT FONT STYLES (on wrapper element not input directly) */
.formInput .MuiOutlinedInput-root
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Roboto, serif
}

/* BORDER COLOR */
.formInput .MuiOutlinedInput-root fieldset
{
    border-color: #057FA8;
}

/* BORDER COLOR ON HOVER */
.formInput .MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover fieldset
{
    border-color: #057FA8
}

/* BORDER COLOR ON FOCUS*/
.formInput .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused fieldset
{
    border-color: #057FA8
}
```

and

```
import styles from './Styles.module.css';

const classes = { root: styles.formInput };

const ExampleComponent = () => {
    return (
        <TextField 
            id="name" 
            name="name" 
            label="Name" 
            classes={classes}
            margin='normal'
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CSS Modules, but basically if you put the class name that gets generated by the CSS module as the `root` property on `classes` it should allow you to do what you want. See this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fkuqh4?file=src%2FApp.js) using normal CSS.